# svg path stroke animation infinite

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I have for example a `svg` path that it looks like a circle. I tried to make it animate more than once by using a for loop. but it does not work.
This is the javascript I use to animate the stroke.

```
var loading = function() {

    path = new Array();
    length = new Array();

    path[0] = document.getElementById('loader1');
   length = path[0].getTotalLength();
   path[0].style.transition = path[0].style.WebkitTransition = 'none';

   length[0] = length;
   path[0].style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + length;
   path[0].style.strokeDashoffset = length;

   path[0].getBoundingClientRect();
   path[0].style.transition = path[0].style.WebkitTransition = 'stroke-dashoffset 2s ease-in-out';

   path[0].style.strokeDashoffset = '0';

};

loading();
```

I would like to make it like a `gif` that animates all the time. if anyone could help I would appreciate it!

This is an example http://jsfiddle.net/6Lqkc2qs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A transition can only go between two styles. You need a CSS animation rather than a transition.

```css
.container
    {
        position:absolute;
        width:500px;
        height:500px;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        margin:auto;
    }

@keyframes changedash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 502.7825622558594px;
    stroke-dasharray: 502.7825622558594 502.7825622558594;
  }

  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
    stroke-dasharray: 502.7825622558594 502.7825622558594;
  }
}

path {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: changedash;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  width="650px" height="650px" viewBox="0 0 650 650" enable-background="new 0 0 650 650" xml:space="preserve">
   <path id="loader1" style="fill:none;stroke:#37c280;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M364.088,203.794c-15.126,2.056-30.18,9.004-44.175,14.744
 c-12.281,5.037-21.834,12.462-30.789,22.188c-24.832,26.97-19.915,68.42,2.081,96.419c28.676,36.505,100.901,36.35,126.027-4.641
 c14.806-24.154,17.992-67.197,0.505-90.905c-16.543-22.427-38.719-29.067-62.473-34.865" style="stroke-dasharray: 502.7825622558594 502.7825622558594; stroke-dashoffset: 502.7825622558594px;"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: is it possible to animate only forward and not backward ? i found it animation-direction: forwards; thank you very much!

Comment: Sure, that's controlled by the animation-direction property. I've changed it in the answer so that it doesn't run backwards.